# file pointer increment in a function will it stay at that increment if you execute again?

Tags: c

I'm programing in c I have a file and a function that grabs a word from a file pointer (removing punctuation and caps).

What I want to know is if the increment will be in the same position if I execute the `getnextword` to get the next word?

Comment: `getnextword` is not a standard function, so we have no way of knowing its behavior.

Comment: Please add a [mre]

Comment: get next word increments through the file pointer until a word is in a buffer which is then cleaned of punctuation and caps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on how you are reading the file, but if you are reading it using e.g. fscanf or something like that, the FILE you are reading will be advanced after executing the function, and subsequent calls to the function will start where they left off in the FILE. If you wanted to start from the same position as before you'd need something like fseek to set the position in the file. If you're using the usual fopen/fgetc/fscanf/fread functions for file IO based on FILE* then a function calling read methods on FILE* I think typically will advance the file position and that will persist across calls to your function, IF you are using the same FILE.